# how to be redirected to the previous page using response.redirect() in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Right now i have a folder with another folder inside of it. The two folder names are called "pc details" and "pchardwaredetails"

When on a page in "pchardwaredetails" i want to return to a page in "pc details" using a button and response.redirect() but the file paths are just getting too complicated for me. What might the file path be from a page called "Details" in "pchardwaredetails" to a page called "viewMore" in "pc details"?

Also please feel free to explain how paths work so i know for future

thanks

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Usually the `Referrer` of the page (a HTTP header), tells you what page you've come from so to go back you should just be able to do:

```
Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
```

That's assuming you `came` from `PC Details`. However if you `land` on `PC Hardware Details` from some other page then that won't work, you would have to hard code the back feature.

You can simplify ASP.NET paths and use `~`, for example:

```
Response.Redirect("~/some/path/pc_details.aspx");
```

Comment: Would this work if you were also going forward from the same page though? i mean in theory you could have multiple entry points into the same page

Comment: @user2500842 Yes that won't work if you come from other pages, you'd have to hard code the back feature to go to the page you want.