# How To Used The Same Web Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have three web forms in asp.net

1. Student
2. Parents
3. Search

Student

[image]

Parents

[image]

Search

[image]

On Form `Student` and `Parents` have the same button `Search`, when we click on it it's redirect to form `Search`

**Question**

When i clicked `Search` it redirect to the web page that we has been search, I mean that on form `Student` and and form `Parent` used the same form `Search`.

So how can we solve the problem?

Comment: I've  modified your question and included the images you've posted as links. Please edit your question again to fix wrong modifications.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery to Submit your form:

Example :

```
<form action="http://test.com">
     <input type="submit" value="FirstForm"/>
</form>
<form action="http://test.com/2">
     <input type="submit" value="SecondForm"/>
</form>
<form action="http://test.com/3">
     <input type="submit" value="SecondForm"/>
</form>
```

Now Place Jquery to submit your forms uniquely:

```
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    $(this).submit();
});
```

Now this will only submit the form which you have submitted.

Hope this works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem already answered in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339346/how-to-be-redirected-to-the-previous-page-using-response-redirect-in-asp-net-c#answer-17339370). Another options you can use is by passing the source page in a "**query string**" or in a **session**